# How to use ROS services

Tags: ros, messages, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get data from a gps and use it in a program that I am writing. I read somewhere that ROS services would be an ideal tool for me to use to accomplish my task. I read over the tutorial that ROS provides but I am still having troubles understanding how to use them. In the links below I have the information that I need for my program to work.

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geographic_msgs/html/msg/GeoPose.html
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geographic_msgs/html/msg/GeoPoint.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215223/how-to-use-ros-services/) by [negotiator14](https://answers.ros.org/users/23016/negotiator14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-08-04**:
well negotiator14, could you use messages communication instead of services since this are messages files?

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-08-05**:
And the question is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You use messages for many-to-many communication over [ROS Topics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics), whereas [Services](http://wiki.ros.org/Services) provide Request/Response communication.

So both could be used what you try to do, depending on your actual use case.

See the [Tutorials Page on the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), especially the Beginner tutorial sections 10. for creating msgs and srvs, 11-13 for Topic communication via Publisher/Subscribers and 14-16 for Services.
From the explanation there, the differences should become clear.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [negotiator14](https://answers.ros.org/users/23016/negotiator14/) on 2015-08-05**:
So what I need for my program to work is a latitude and a longitude and I need to get it from the geographic_msgs/GeoPoint.msg message but I am still not sure on how to do that. Once I get those two points then my program uses them to send some files to a user.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-06**:
This seems to be a typical use case for a Subscriber. (Assuming you already have a node that works as a driver for the GPS device and publishes this message)
See the Tutorials Page on the ROS Wiki, beginner level, Tutorials 11-13 for this.

If you have a specific question, please post a new one.